# Is gmail watch API idempotent?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gmail, gmail-api, google-cloud-pubsub

I am using [`Gmail watch`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users/watch) API to listen to user's inbox updates. Whenever a new email comes on user mailbox, Google sends it on my webhook.

**Question:**

Is this API idempotent?

**Explanation:**

I mean if I call this API twice. Will it create two watches on the inbox and I will receive each update two times? **or** it will only create 1 watch on the user's inbox regardless of how many times I call this API.

Comment: What do you mean, on the same channel? If so this will renew the watch as mentioned [Renewing mailbox watch](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push#renewing_mailbox_watch)

Comment: @Kessy Thanks for the link. I think it cleared my concerns about duplication of listeners. So It means that it just refreshes the watch whenever I call it. Whether after 7 days, or multiple times a day. It will only refresh the watch. That makes the API idempotent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting my comment into an answer.

Going through [the link](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push#renewing_mailbox_watch) shared by Kessy in the comment cleared my concerns about the duplication of listeners. So It means that it just refreshes the `watch` whenever I call it. Whether after 7 days, or multiple times a day. It will only refresh the `watch`. **That makes the API idempotent.**